# Xaml Binding outside itemtemplate

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I would like to bind data of my listbox. Imagine I have something like :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text={Binding Value} />
        <TextBlock Text={Binding AbsoluteValue} />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

MyList contains an observable collection of an object that has a property named "Value"
AbsoluteValue is a property of the view model, as the MyList property.

Of course, the seconde textbox will have always the same value, but it is what I want :)

How can I tell the binding that the datacontext is not the same for the second textbox ?

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT : my real sample is a StackPanel. 
I've tryed

```
private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
    stackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, new Binding("Loaded") { Source = DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }); 
}
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbAbsoluteValue" Loaded="AbsoluteValue_Loaded" />
```

Codebehind:

```
void AbsoluteValue_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock absoluteValue = sender as TextBlock;

    absoluteValue.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("AbsoluteValue") { Source = VIEW_MODEL_OBJECT, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
}
```

That's one way to achieve what you want, you could also use a converter too, or create a `StaticResource` in your `Resources` for the VM and bind to that as a source.

Comment: In fact, this is not a textbox, but a StackPanel with VisibilityProperty. I've tryed :         private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
            stackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, new Binding("Loaded") { Source = DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }); 
        }
but it's not working

Comment: I'm assuming your Loaded property on your VM is a Boolean? VisibilityProperty is of Visibility type. You need a converter. (Bool to Visibility)

Comment: oh yes, forget to use it :(
stackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, new Binding("Loaded") { Source = DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Converter = new VisibilityConverter() }); 
it's ok with that :) thanks